# Junction table referencing non existent entity

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, database-integrity

I have the following models in django

```py
class WorkSession(models.Model):
    pass

class Invoice(models.Model):

    work_sessions = models.ManyToManyField(WorkSession, blank=True)
```

what I noticed is that when i do the following:

```py
invoice = Invoice()
session = WorkSession(a=a, b=b)
invoiceo.work_sessions.set([session])
```

The invoice_worksession junction table gets populated with a relation, even though I haven't saved invoice yet.
Meaning that the invoices table, there's no row, but in the junction table, there's a row that references an invoice that doesn't exist yet.
Is this normal ?

Because this is causing an integrity error on fixture teardown since the invoice doesn't exist and yet, there's a refrence to
an invoice id in the junction table

**EDIT**

The following is a better explanation of what I'm trying to do and the problem itself

Here are my tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE "drscm_worksession" (
    "id"    char(32) NOT NULL,
    "start_timestamp"    integer NOT NULL,
    "end_timestamp"    integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id"),

);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE "drscm_invoice" (
    "id"    char(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id"),
);
```

and the junction table

```sql
CREATE TABLE "drscm_invoice_work_sessions" (
    "id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "invoice_id"    char(32) NOT NULL,
    "worksession_id"    char(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    FOREIGN KEY("invoice_id") REFERENCES "drscm_invoice"("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    FOREIGN KEY("worksession_id") REFERENCES "drscm_worksession"("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
```

The **objective** is to create an invoice in the database with work_sessions **via** an api call.

The data i would need to send over, using my api client is this:

```json
{work_sessions: [uuid1, uuid2] }
```

so the code would be

```py
url = "/invoices/"
ws1 = WorkSession().save()
ws2 = WorkSession().save()
data = {'work_sessions': [ws1.id, ws2.id] }
self.client.post(path=url, data=data)
```

This works PERFECTLY.
BUT,
I thought, I don't want to have to write these objects manually as they get bigger in the real test.
So the approach was to do this:

```py
invoice = Invoice()
invoice.work_sessions.set([ws1, ws2])
data = InvoiceSerializer(instance=invoice).data
self.client.post(path=url, data=data)
```

This does create the invoice with the according sessions BUT throws an `IntegrityError` exception during the `teardown` phase of the test

Here's why it throws the exception:

1. `Invoice()` creates an instance of the object and that instance has an `id`, but the invoice is NOT in the database
2. `invoice.work_sessions.set([ws1, ws2])` creates 2 rows in the **drscm_invoice_work_sessions** table (junction table), and the `invoice_id` column takes the id of the NOT CREATED `invoice` instance. ( Which is the bug here)
3. During teardown, it tries do delete the relations in the junction table --> looks  for an invoice with id: `invoice.id` in the `drscm_invoices` table, but it doesn't exit.
   --> Throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the objects first to the database, such that these have a primary key, so:

```
invoice = Invoice.objects.create()
session = WorkSession.objects.create(a=a, b=b)
invoice.work_sessions.add(session)
```

Comment: What I'm testing is my view.
So I'm creating the object via the test api client.
So the invoice will be serialized and sent over as the body of the HTTP request.
Unless my method is wrong

Comment: And isn't this a bug ? The fact that the junction contains a reference to a non existing object ? Because the fact that I haven't the invoice itself was done on purpose.
I was just trying to have a JSON with the necessary values to create my entity

Comment: @Amrou: most databases with integrity constraints enabled, will not enable this no. So normally if you have a proper database, that will be rejected by the database.

Comment: @Amrou it's true, it looks weird and it's not documented well in the documentation. You should get an integrity error on `set` call, not later, right?

Comment: @vinkomlacic Exactly !

Comment: @vinkomlacic: this is not Django's responsibility: Django simply creates a query. The database should raise the integrity error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can I fix this then ? 
I tried it with postgres and sqlite and it's the same issue that occurs :/

Comment: @Amrou you 'll need to create objects first as suggested by WillemVanOnsem, then you can add or set the corresponding key in invoice table.

Comment: I've updated my question @SukhpreetSingh, because I feel like I'm not explaining it good enough to understand what I'm trying to do. Sorry for that